# Ayuda con programa que reemplaza palabras

Tags: java

Tengo que realizar el siguiente ejercicio en Java con Eclipse:

> Escriba un programa en Java que en primer lugar lea de la consola dos palabras: la primera se denominará patrón y la segunda substitución. Seguidamente el programa leerá de consola de forma interactiva una serie de líneas de texto hasta leer una línea vacía. Por cada línea leída debe analizar si en ella se encuentra una o varias veces la palabra patrón, y si esto ocurre, mostrar la línea cambiando la  palabra patrón por la palabra substitución en todas las ocurrencias. Antes de finalizar su ejecución debe mostrar el número de líneas en las que ha encontrado la palabra patrón.

La verdad es que no tengo mucha idea de cómo abarcar este programa. He pensado en algo así:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class palabrasT {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        String patron;
        String texto;
        String vacia = "";
        int contador = 0;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        do{
            System.out.println("Introduzca un patron");
            patron = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Introduzca una linea");
            texto = sc.nextLine();
            String array [] = texto.split("");

            for (int i = 0; i<array.length;i++) {
                if(array[i].equals("patron"))
                    System.out.println(texto.replace(patron, texto));
                contador++;
            }
        } while(texto!=null);
        sc.close();
        System.out.println("La palabra patron aparece" +contador + "veces");

    }
}
```

Pero al compilarlo y ejecutarlo me sale un bucle que pide

> Introduzca una linea
>
> Introduzca un patron
>
> Introduzca una linea
>
> ...

Answer (score 1):

Hola te ayudo con tu problema.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class palabrasT {

  public static void main(String[]args) {

    String patron;      
    String texto;
    String vacia = "";
    int contador = 0;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);    
    System.out.println("Introduzca un patron");
    patron = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Introduzca un texto de substitucion");
    texto= sc.nextLine();

    while(sc.hasNext()){
       vacia=sc.nextLine();
       if(vacia.contains(patron)){
           texto=texto.replaceAll(patron,texto);
           contador++; 
       }
    }


    System.out.println("La palabra patron aparece" +contador + "veces");

   }
}
```

tu problema es que el patron y el texto de remplazo deben estar fuera del do while. y te falta una sentencia para ir leyendo las lineas , pero con el código que modifique,  funciona.